# Add JS Event Listener to Chrome Extension Popup

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, event-listener

I'm building a Chrome Extension, and I'm having some trouble adding an event listener. I want to add it to a button within the popup.

Here's the JS -

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    document.getElementById('checkButton').onclick = grabLinks;
});
```

And here's the popup HTML -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>

<script src="background.js"></script>

    </head>
<body>

    <h3>Duplink</h3>

    <p>Check if a link is already on this page.</p>
    <form>
            URL: <input id="URL" type="text" name="URL"><br>
            <input id='checkButton' type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

    <p>Link is:<span id="message"></span></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Also, here's the manifest.json just in case -

```
{
    "name": "Duplink",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Check for duplicate links on DotDash sites",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "background": {
      "scripts": [
        "background.js",
        "popup.js"],
      "persistent": false
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_title": "Duplink"
      },
      "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "storage"
      ]
}
```

When I unpack the extension, I get this error. - **Error in event handler: TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null**

Then it keeps repeating this error over and over again. - **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addListener' of undefined**

Comment: Could you provide your full `popup.html`?

Comment: I added the full popup.html (Without CSS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use addEventListener to bind the event to button also:

Check the code below:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var btn = document.getElementById('checkButton');
    btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
        alert("button clicked");
    });
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that results in the same Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null. =/

Comment: should that code be in background or content.js?

Comment: Hi @Daniyaldehleh this code should be in popup.js

Comment: This code has to be placed in external JS file and referenced in the popup.html

Answer (score 1):

Your `popup.js` should be added into `popup.html` instead of add to background scripts. Like so:

```
    "background": {
      "scripts": [
        "background.js"
      ],
      "persistent": false
    },
```

and then your `popup.js` should be placed in `popup.html`:

```
<h3>Duplink</h3>
...
<p>Link is:<span id="message"></span></p>

<script src="popup.js"></script>
```

Comment: I already had it included on the page. I also tried moving to the bottom to defer the load, but that didn't do anything either.

Comment: I saw that you add background.js instead of popup.js. Those error should come when you inspect your popup, instead of come in background context.

Answer (score 0):

I figured some things out!

I changed the input type to button to prevent the default action. (Submitting a form) -

```
 <h3>Duplink</h3>

    <p>Check if a link is already on this page.</p>
    <form>
            URL: <input id="URL" type="text" name="URL"><br>
            <input id='checkButton' type="button" value="Submit">
    </form>

    <p>Link is:<span id="message"></span></p>
```

And put binded the event to the button.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

    var btn = document.getElementById('checkButton');

    btn.addEventListener('click', function() {

    //Get URL from input
    var URL = document.getElementById('URL').value;

    //Get all links
    var links = document.querySelectorAll('.article a');

    //Convert Nodelist to Array
    var linksArr = [];
    links.forEach(node => linksArr.push(node.href))

    //Compare Link to Array
    var compareArr = linksArr.includes(URL);

    //Alert if link exists on page, or not
        if (compareArr === true) {
            document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = " On the page - Don't Add Link";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = ' Not on the page - Add Link';
        }
   });
});
```